# PlayFramework strict routes and ajax

Tags: ajax, playframework-2.0

Question could be obvious but I still cannot find appropriate solution for this.

Lets assume there is a controller with only one method:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    public static Result sum(int op1, int op2) {
        return ok(op1 + op2);
    }
}
```

Routes file is simple enough too:

```
GET /sum    controllers.MyController.sum(op1: Integer, op2: Integer)
```

Well, now I can do call from templates:

```
@controllers.routes.MyController.sum(1, 2)
```

which will be translated to

```
localhost:9000/sum?op1=1&op2=2
```

, or directly paste this url in browser. This works pretty ok.

But everything goes bad when I decide to use ajax for doing this.
I am not js-guru, so I write small (and bad I think:) object using jQuery which adds onClick handler to button. Here it is:

```
entityController.setSumURL = function(sumURL) {
    this.sumURL = sumURL;
}

entityController.bindSumButton = function(buttonId, op1, op2) {
    $.get(entityController.sumURL, {op1: op1, op2, op2}, function(){
        alert("Done!");
    });
}
```

where entityController.sumURL should be url to /sum method. 
Usually when I render page view I write something like this:

```
@()
....
entityController.setSumURL("@controllers.routes.MyController.sum()")
....
```

But I cannot do this because sum method has mandatory arguments and there is no way to get address only because binded url can rely on parametes passed to function defined in routes.

So the question is how to do get path only from url without arguments, or how to reorganize whole process to avoid such situations?

My solution is to remove arguments from function appearing in routes and query them directly from request, but my project is growing and sometimes it become too hard to understand which parameters are passed to method.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [zen tasks](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/zentasks) sample application.

In particular:

- the [javascriptRoutes](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/controllers/Application.java) method in the controller
- the references to jsRoutes in the [coffeescript](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/app/assets/javascripts/main.coffee)
- the [routes](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/zentasks/conf/routes) config

You may want to compile this app and look at the output javascript rather than the coffeescript if you're not familiar with coffeescript.

Also, if you're reloading parts of the page using ajax, you may want to bind your jQuery using

```
$('.somePermanentContainer').on('click', 'selectorForClickable', function()...)
```

otherwise you'll find it's no longer bound when that part of the DOM is reloaded.